# How can I get ufraw in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I used `ufraw-batch` in my Nautilus scripts like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    picture=$1
    ufraw-batch --out-type jpg "$picture"
    shift
done
```

It helped me a lot for generating previews of raw photos, located in different file-servers.

I have installed 20.04 and found, that `ufraw-batch` is not in repos anymore. What can I do?

Thanks for the answer, this is my new script using `dcraw` and `imagick` instead, hope it helps somebody:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    picture=$1
    j_file=`echo "$picture" | sed 's/\.\w*$/.jpg/'`
    dcraw -c -w "$picture" | convert - "$j_file"
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seem that ufraw is unmaintained => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFRaw

You can use instead dcraw .

Comment: dcraw doesn't seem to replace ufraw. Previously, with ufraw-batch installed, I could use the `convert` (from ImageMagick) utility to convert DNG files to JPG files. With dcraw installed, I can no longer do this.

Comment: @RaleighL.  may be this can help  http://www.kevinludlow.com/blog/Configuring_ImageMagick_RAW_Delegates_with_DCRAW_and_UFRAWBatch/1240258/

Answer (score 4):

I just found this q&a because ufraw is missing in my distro as well. I know this is an old thread, but your script above can be improved like this:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    picture=$1
    dcraw -c -w "$picture" | convert - ${picture%\.*}.jpg"
    shift
done
```

So there is no need to call `echo` and `sed`.

Comment: `convert - ${` should be `convert - "${ ` but SO won't allow me to make edits less than 8 characters :)

Answer (score 0):

Source is at http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/.  But it's an old program which uses a few things not available any more. Gtkimageview was the last thing I ran into, it's a generic image scratchpad they shouldn't have used because when that went away it broke everything.  Like Windows used IE for drawing text on screen, it was really needed.

I have seen a version that uses output to some other file format, that's semi-usable.  Could maybe be rewritten to use GTK instead, not sure I'm up to it or have the time.  But without ufraw I can't do photography because nothing else is usable and I was just getting into star pictures.